# RxJava2: How to wait all Flowables in a list to finish?

Tags: java, rx-java2

Suppose I have a list of `Flowable`, and I would like to do something until all `Flowable` are finished, how can I do it?

## Sample Code

```
List<Flowable<Model>> flowableList = getFlowableList();
List<List<Model>> results = blockUntilAllFlowablesAreFinished(flowableList); // is there a similar method?
... // do something with results
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use `Flowable.zip()` with `Iterable` as parameter, it will emit when all Flowables in Iterable are done.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure why you are thinking in a synchronous fashion but I believe you'll achieve your goal with something like:

```
Flowable.combineLatest(flowableList -> {
    // do something with results
});
```

Of course, besides `combineLatest`, there are bunch of operators that allow you to "combine" flowables e.g. `zip`. Choose one that suit you here https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/Combining-Observables